# Encoding BufferedImage to Base64 in JRuby (Java)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I'm dynamically creating a BufferedImage and trying to encode it to Base64 string so that I can display an image in template like so:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64, [base 65 string]>
```

I have a BufferedImage variable which I tried to write to disk for test and the image gets written successfully:

```
ImageIO.write(@img, "gif", Java::JavaIo::File.new(filename))
```

How can I obtain bytes string from the @img variable (without writing to disk) so that I can encode it into Base64 and display it in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a `StringIO` in a [`org.jruby.util.IOOutputStream`](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/util/IOOutputStream.html) with the `to_outputstream` method and write to that, then get the bytes with `StringIO#string`:

```
sio = StringIO.new
outputstream = sio.to_outputstream

ImageIO.write(@img, "gif", outputstream)

encoded = Base64.encode64(sio.string)
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I had to remove newline characters from encoded string to make it work though.

Comment: @MaticJurglič it seemed to work OK when I tested, it probably depends on the browser.  You can use [`strict_encode64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64) to generate the Base 64 encoded string without newlines rather than stripping them afterwards.